# error installation

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, python

I use `sudo pip3 install pyarrow` and it got me an error
Command "`python setup.py egg_info`" failed with `error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-q2wrajvr/pyarrow/`
i used `pip3 install pyarrow`
but it got me messege that `Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.10 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pyarrow) (1.15.0)`
and the real problem is whem i use
import pyarrow as pa` in python 3.7 i see this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarrow'
```

how could i solve it

Comment: try `python3 setup.py egg_info`

Comment: python3: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: in my case, if you install via pip3 you should use python3, sir

Comment: sudo python3 setup.py egg_info
[sudo] password for lenovo: 
python3: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: sudo apt-get install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 51 not upgraded.

Comment: "51 not upgraded", you need to run `sudo apt dist-upgrade`

Comment: okay and what should do i after upgrade it

Comment: dist-upgrade perform smart upgrade. after you do it, try to start over install pyarrow

Comment: File "/tmp/pip-install-43fitjo9/pyarrow/.eggs/setuptools_scm-3.0.6-py3.7.egg/setuptools_scm/__init__.py", line 44, in _version_from_entrypoint
        for ep in iter_matching_entrypoints(config.absolute_root, entrypoint):
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'absolute_root'
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-43fitjo9/pyarrow/

Comment: could you tell me the commands you have run to install pyarrow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [setuptools](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/) doesn't seem installed.
If it's already installed, try

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

or

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools --user python
```

If it's already up to date, check that the module ez_setup is not missing. If it is, then

```
pip install ez_setup
```

Then try again

```
pip3 install pyarrow
```

The [Installation instruction](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/) from PyPI website

Comment: Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in ./bin (40.0.0)

Comment: Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.

Comment: > import pyarrow as pa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarrow'